# OOM while heap dump shows free space

Tags: java, multithreading, heap-memory

I have an application that keeps throwing OOM exceptions, however when I review the heap dumps there is always some amount of unused heap space.  Does anyone have an idea why this might happen?  I was thinking that maybe an object was getting created that cause the OOM but wouldn't that show up in the heap dump?

***EDIT***
settings:
/usr/local/jre/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -server -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8998 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/common/endorsed -classpath :/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/commons-logging-api.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you are getting(the OOM) you are seeing.

Comment: How do you expect the object, which creation caused the OOMError, to appear in the heap dump? The OOMError was thrown, because there was no room in the heap to create the instance. At least if the OOMError is caused by heap exhaustion.

Comment: Define "some amount of heap space". Define how and when you are examining the heap space.

Comment: Please also post all flags you are passing to the JVM

Comment: OOM can be raised for the exhaustion of many kinds of memory space in the VM, e.g. permanent generation.

Comment: I can't define "some amount of heap" because its different every time. one example of the amount that was shown as unallocated was 1.2GB and I can't imagine that any object would be to big to fit in that.

Comment: As was already reqired, please show the _full_ error. Does it actually say `OutOfMemoryError: heap space`?